# Google Analytics, Deep Links, and the Cornerstone platform

Tags: web, google-analytics, deep-linking, deeplink, cornerstone

Developers!

I need your help.

My team uses, "Cornerstone", as a Learning Management System platform. I make custom pages that show deep links to courses. I have never been able to see Google Analytic results for "deep links". After clicking a deep link, the user is 'registered' and marked as 'completed' for taking the course.

Google Analytics is not tracking deep links. But, It is tracking other links to pages just fine. Do you why? How can I solve?

**Here is what a "deep link" looks like:**

https://sephora.csod.com/samldefault.aspx?returnurl=%252fDeepLink%252fProcessRedirect.aspx%253fmodule%253dloRegisterAndLaunch%2526lo%253de37bea16-2097-4c94-a900-3f9052beba53

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

- Matie, Web Designer

Comment: You expect us to click on that?

Comment: No, ;) I was hoping you could read the URL path, and help figure out how to get Google to track a link like this.... It's a system feature, to wrap links like this. It registers the user and assigns them to a training...

Comment: I need help with **Google Analytics** and getting tracking on a link like this.